# How to make two keyboards appear on screen

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, keyboard

Is there any way to have two keyboards on the screen at once? I have an app that two people can use at the same time: one part of the app takes one half of the screen and the other part takes the other half and is flipped. It will have text fields, and it would be a flaw for only one person to be able to use it at a time. Is it possible to do this?

If not, would I have to make my own keyboard? That's fine, but I have one question: how exactly do you add a character to the end of a NSString?

Is any of this against guidelines? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I think you will have to add your own keyboard.  There are companies that sell libraries that implement custom keyboards.  Getting it flipped is a problem; if you have the source to the keyboard library, you can use Affine Transforms to flip it upside down.

You can't add anything to an existing NSString as NSString is immutable.  Your two choices are to use an NSMutableString or to create a totally new string out of your existing string and a string containing the one character that you want to add.

Comment: You don't NEED the source to flip the keyboard, if it's just a UIView (and it probably is), it's as easy as adding a transform to it.

Comment: Do you know of any places I could download the custom keyboard? I can't seem to find anything...

Comment: Isn't as simple as linking an IBAction to a button, and if that button is tapped, add a key to the NSMutableString?

Comment: I saw a Google ad for custom iOS keyboards a while back, but I don't have a link.  You probably won't find them in the app store, as what you'll be buying is an executable code library rather than an app.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure it's not possible.

As for adding a char to the end of the string, it's as easy as using an NSMutableString and do `[mutableString appendString:anotherString];`